# How to change number in an element

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an element with a '&nbsp' in it. I'm trying to increment the number by 1 whenever a button on the page is clicked. I've been trying but keep getting not a number (NaN) output.

```
    var counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemCounter").innerText);
    const AddToCart = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("AddToCart"));
    
    AddToCart.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            counter = counter+1;
            document.getElementById("itemCounter").innerText = parseInt(counter)
        })
    });
```

Here's what I tried could someone please point out my mistake?
Thanks

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your HTML as well.

Comment: Use the code snippet tool and edit the rest of your CSS/HTML code into the question so we can reproduce the issue as a MRE.

Comment: `.innerText = parseInt(counter)` The parseInt there is useless since you are storing it into a string.

Comment: It is an empty space, why are you trying to convert it to a number? Can it have a number in it when the page renders?

Comment: change this **var counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemCounter").innerText);** to **var counter = 0;** You don't need to grab the value of innerText on page load if it is just empty.

Comment: The code works fine even with a &nbsp; provided there is a starting number included, like zero.  Regardless, @imvain2 suggestion to use a var is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt` when it is not a number will return `NaN`. So you can add an `or` to set it to zero when it runs into this state.

```js
var counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemCounter").innerText) || 0;
const AddToCart = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("AddToCart"));

AddToCart.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    document.getElementById("itemCounter").innerText = counter
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="itemCounter">&nbsp;</div>

<button class="AddToCart">Foo 1</button>
<button class="AddToCart">Foo 2</button>
<button class="AddToCart">Foo 3</button>
```